# Implementing custom tag/tax pages

Tags: php, themes

My question has a couple of aspects:

My current custom theme is fairly vanilla, with a homepage, tag/tax index page and content page templates.

I want to be able to have a couple of custom layout templates for tag pages, so rather than the template hierarchy simply loading the template php, I want to:

- check to see if this tag id/ slug has a custom layout
- if it does, load it, with its custom layout elements
- if not, load the default template

My site is quite high traffic so I'm looking for a solution that doesn't have a huge performance overhead. Ideally at the point of determining if we're loading something custom, I want to know if Wordpress makes available the tag/tax ID or slug so I can do a nice quick lookup on my custom table.

Comment: `template_include` filter plus `get_queried_object_id()` plus `locate_template` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tag_template` or `taxonomy_template` filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) and check the queried object from within that, then use [`locate_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) to get the template path.

```
function wpd_tag_template_filter( $templates = '' ) {
    $this_tag = get_queried_object();
    // check $this_tag->term_id, $this_tag->slug, etc.
    $templates = locate_template( 'my_custom_template.php', false );
    return $templates;
}
add_filter( 'tag_template', 'wpd_tag_template_filter' );
```